# jQuery keeps prepending another button when I resize screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, media-queries

I am trying to hide paragraphs when the screen is less than 480px and prepend a button "read more" to open the hidden paragraphs.

I have tried the following code, however, after the screen is resized the button is now present for all other screen sizes. Any tips as to where I am going wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        /*  Hide content and append a button to show more content
        ======================================================================== */
        $(window).resize(function() {
            if ($(window).width() <= 480) {
                $('#first_text_paragraphs').append('<button>Read More</button>');
            /* toggle Read more button
            ============================================= */
            $('button').on("click", function() {
                $('.about_text_paragraphs').slideToggle();
            });
            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: You put `.on("click"` inside the `resize` so each time you resize the window there will be another `click` event listener attached to every single button...

Comment: Also, you shouldn't use JavaScript for this kind of stuff. That's what CSS is for.

Comment: Thank you for that comment I couldn't understand why everytime I resized it I got another appended button. In future, I will use CSS I thought I'd try my hand at jQuery to improve and see if I could do it. But all this helps tremendously.

Answer (score 2):

General tips:

1. Instead of appending the element, just have it always there, and use the `display` CSS property to toggle it as desired.
2. If you do something when the width drops below 480 pixels, you need to perform the inverse operation when the width goes above 480 pixels or else whatever you did will continue to persist.
3. If you're going to add an element to the page when some condition is met, you should use a flag (or comparable mechanism) to ensure that you don't add the element multiple times.  For instance, if the user resizes to 470 pixels, and then again to 460 pixels.  You don't want to append the button twice.
4. [Media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) are your friend.  They can do what you want with far less code.  However, I'll assume that you're interested in a programmatic approach here.

In terms of specifics, I would code it roughly like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#readMore').on("click", function() {
        $('.about_text_paragraphs').slideToggle();
    });

    if ($(window).width() <= 480) {
        $("#readMore").show();
    }

    /*  Hide content and append a button to show more content
        ======================================================================== */
    $(window).resize(function() {
        if ($(window).width() <= 480) {
            $("#readMore").show();
        }
        else {
            $("#readMore").hide();
        }
    });

});
```

Here's a fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/FFuvG/

Or, you can take bjb568's **excellent** advice and simply use CSS media queries to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for explaining my mistake, it makes a lot more sense now. I guess CSS is a better option for this.

Comment: If I was writing this code I would just add `.trigger("resize")` after `.resize` so that I don't need another `if($(window).width() <= 480`. :D

Answer (score 1):

jQuery abuse! Use CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    #mytext {
        max-height: 200px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    #mybutton {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="mytext">lorem ipsum</div>
<button id="mybutton" hidden>Read More</button>
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/72dbN/)**

This should be much faster then jQuery (as with everything CSS).

Comment: ha ha that's hilarious. Ok, I will try this now and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: Your right, CSS a better option for this. Much simpler too.

Comment: One does not simply use too much jQuery! It solves every single problem in the Universe! BTW have you tried the [jQuery diet plugin](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/YEwUZ/514/

Here is one where the button shows up:
http://jsfiddle.net/YEwUZ/515/

See if the demo is what you are trying to accomplish by moving the width of the output area.

**HTML**

```
<div class="button">
    This is a Button
</div>
<div class="mydiv">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.button { 
    background:#fefefe;
    width:100px;
    text-align:center;
    margin:5px;
    padding:5px 15px; 
    border:1px solid #eee;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:480px) {
    .mydiv {display:none;}   
}
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.button').click(function() {
           if ( $( ".mydiv" ).is( ":hidden" ) ) {
            $('.mydiv').fadeIn();

           } else {
            $('.mydiv').fadeOut();

         }
      });
 });
```